# How to display the text in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display the error message in a textbox in MVC. I used following code for that but its not displaying.

```
userProgram.CompileOutput  = "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                            ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                            ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

@Html.EditorFor(up => up.CompileOutput)
return View(userProgram);
```

In the above code userProgram returns the value for CompileOutput. But its not displaying in the textbox.

Comment: What is CompileOutput a string or object?

Comment: Please be more detailed. Specify your View code and controller codes.

Comment: @hutchonoid - its string.

Comment: @nikhilsreeni - It does not show any error. Just its not showing anything.

Comment: Are you using the `@Html` helper inside the controller, instead of inside the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try it,

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this to show `textbox`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(up => up.CompileOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CompileOutput` is a string you could use the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(up => up.CompileOutput)
```

If it is a complex object you need to define the EditorTemplate for that type.

Answer (score 0):

add this row top of view page.

```
@model YourNamespace.yourModel
```

and change this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompileOutput)
```